# How to plot the discrte form of the logistic model in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to plot y(k) againts k of the following formula in matlab:

```
             y(k+1)=r(y(k))(1-y(k))
```

So I did the following:

```
%Logistic model in its discrete form.
r=2.5;
y=rand(1);
for j=1:100
        y(j+1)=r*y(j)*(1-y(j));

end
plot(y(j+1),j)
```

but when I run it, the only thing that gives me is a white plot, this is, only the axis. What did I do wrong here?, Can you help me to fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create array of values of function.

```
%Logistic model in its discrete form.
r=2.5;
Y = zeros(100, 1);
Y(1) = rand(1);
for j=1:100
    Y(j+1)=r*Y(j)*(1-Y(j));
end
plot(1:101, Y)
```

Plot function get two arrays, first values of x axis, second values of y axis.

Comment: Ok, let me check, thanks a lot for reading my question :), give a while

Comment: It gives a lot of mistakes :(

Comment: Right :) , do you know what should be the graph of this?, well to have a form of verification

Comment: By default plot function draw a polyline with vertexes on points described by passed arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch `j` and `y` and make sure that `j` is the same length as `y`. You can run the code from my [Saturn Fiddle](https://saturnapi.com/vpartition/how-to-plot-discrete-form-of-logistic-model/edit)

```
%Logistic model in its discrete form.
r=2.5;
y = zeros(100, 1);
y(1) = rand(1);
for j=1:100
    y(j+1)=r*y(j)*(1-y(j));
end
j = 1:length(y);
plot(j, y, '.')
print("MyPNG.png", "-dpng")
```

[image]

https://saturnapi.com/vpartition/how-to-plot-discrete-form-of-logistic-model/edit